# how to connect the Cloud SQL Auth proxy to connect to two same Cloud SQL instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Hi I have two instances with same 5432 ports. I need to connect these instances with sqlproxy.

is this possible or do I need to change the port for one of the instance port?

Using below command:

```
cloud_sql_proxy -instances=myProject:us-central1:myInstance=tcp:5432,myProject:us-central1:myInstance2=tcp:5432
```

Getting below error

> listen tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a different port number for the second instance: **us-central1:myInstance2=tcp:0.0.0.0:5433**

Connect using port 5432 for the first instance and port 5433 for the second instance.

Comment: How can I connect the second instance from pgadmin    Host:127.0.0.1 with port 5433 i tries but getting error

Comment: @JanSeijerlin - I would need details on your connection string and the error.

Comment: This may work with Cloud SQL Proxy 1.0 but it is no longer valid with 2.0 - I receive the following error: `could not resolve version for "PROJECT:REGION:DB_INSTANCE=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306": failed to get instance: Refresh error: failed to get instance metadata (connection name = "PROJECT:REGION:DB_INSTANCE=tcp:0.0.0.0"): googleapi: Error 400: Invalid request: instance name (0.0.0.0)., invalid`